# Programmatically uistackview height not changing according to content ios

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am changing `UIStackview` height according to content whatever i am adding in stackview, Sometimes its showing proper height but sometimes content height showing 40 and `UIStackview` height showing 0.

```
 if bluetoothDisconnectedBanner.superview == nil { 
      bannerStackView.addArrangedSubview(bluetoothDisconnectedBanner) 
  } 
      bannerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewController.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true 
      bannerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewController.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true 
      bannerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewController.view.topAnchor).isActive = true 
      bannerStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Use the following code:
bannerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true bannerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true bannerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
bannerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true 

The problem is that you are not providing the constraints for the bottom constraints.
Add this and let the elements expand according the contents.

Comment: @FionaShoff if you believe that's the answer - you should consider making it an actual answer instead of a comment...

Comment: if your stackview is horizental then add height constraint otherwise add width constraint. and also set fill equel spacing property of uistackview